# How to prove this sum being a real number related to unitary matrices?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Based on my recent study on  non-Abelian gauge theory in physics, I encounter an identity that should be correct physically but I don't know how to prove it mathematically.

Consider a $n\times n$ unitary matrix $U(x,y)\in U(n)$ smoothly depending on two real parameters $x,y$, let $u_{ij}$ be its entities, then does the following relation $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n (\partial_xu_{ij}^*)(\partial_yu_{ij})=\sum_{i,j=1}^n (\partial_xu_{ij})(\partial_yu_{ij}^*)$$ hold ? Which means the sum is a real number (where $u^*$ means the complex conjugate). And how to prove this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantity you're considering on the left is $ {\rm tr}(\partial_x U^* \partial_y U)$.

Since $U U^* = I$ for all $x,y$, the product rule tells us that

$$ \partial_x U \ U^* + U\ \partial_x U^* = 0$$

and thus $$\partial_x U^* = -U^*\  \partial_x U\  U^*.$$

Very similarly we can obtain $$\partial_y U = -U\ \partial_y U^*\ U.$$ Substituting these in, we have (using $U^* U = U U^* = I$ and the cyclic invariance of the trace)

$$ \begin{align}
{\rm tr}(\partial_x U^* \partial_y U) &= {\rm tr}(U^*\  \partial_x U\  U^*U\ \partial_y U^*\ U)
\\&= {\rm tr} (U^*\  \partial_x U\  \ \partial_y U^*\ U)
\\&= {\rm tr} (U U^*\  \partial_x U\  \ \partial_y U^*)
\\&= {\rm tr} (\partial_x U\  \ \partial_y U^*)\end{align}$$
which is your RHS.